# Create new column using apply family

Tags: r, apply, lapply

In my data frame I have a character column. I'd like to create a new column from the existing character column using a function I've written myself.

My function

```
lat_finder <- function(coord){
return(as.numeric(substr(strsplit(coord,",")[[1]][1],2,10)))}
```

Test data frame

```
test <- data.frame('loc' = c("(37.7862913318072, -122.401375181471)","(37.7646938184545, -122.449439257453)","(37.7860078381928, -122.430650176965)"))
```

I'm trying this

```
test['Lat'] <- lapply(test['loc'],lat_finder)
```

The result is a new column but with only the result of the function of the first row i.e. the first lat should be 37.786... and this is the value for for every row in the new column. I know a for loop would work as I've done this operation before but it takes quite a while so I'd really like to speed this up. I'm sure it's clear I'm missing something under the hood here so in addition to a fix, I'd appreciate an explanation of what my code is doing as is.

Comment: Note: in the original post I incorrectly referenced the entire data frame I was working with. It should have been lapply(test['loc']....) and has been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial note - because your call to data.frame is missing stringsAsFactors = FALSE you are converting your input string as a factor, which makes the problem not repeatable as you state it. That said I think that may just be a problem in your test code and not the root of your actual problem, I'm adding that and going from there:

```
test_f <- data.frame('loc' = c("(37.7862913318072, -122.401375181471)",
                           "(37.7646938184545, -122.449439257453)",
                           "(37.7860078381928, -122.430650176965)"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With that said, your underlying issue is the way you are pulling the column 'loc'. This square-brackets, stringname selection pulls a one-column dataframe:

```
> your_pull <- test_f['loc']
> your_pull
                                    loc
1 (37.7862913318072, -122.401375181471)
2 (37.7646938184545, -122.449439257453)
3 (37.7860078381928, -122.430650176965)
> typeof(your_pull)
[1] "list"
> class(your_pull)
[1] "data.frame"
```

`lapply` is expecting a vector as input, which you can get with the classic `$` notation:

```
> dollar_pull <- test_f$loc
> dollar_pull
[1] "(37.7862913318072, -122.401375181471)" "(37.7646938184545, -122.449439257453)"
[3] "(37.7860078381928, -122.430650176965)"
> typeof(dollar_pull)
[1] "character"
> class(dollar_pull)
[1] "character"
```

The function call works now (expect you are getting a list where you might want a vector - see my incidental notes below):

```
> lapply(test_f$loc,lat_finder)
[[1]]
[1] 37.78629

[[2]]
[1] 37.76469

[[3]]
[1] 37.78601
```

A couple of incidentals:

1) probably a good idea to assign the new column with `$` as well.

2) you might want to use sapply or vapply which will produce a vector rather than a list for your new data.frame column.

3) you might want to abandon the apply family for Hadley Wickham's purr package. For reference the call here would be `purrr::map_chr(test_f$loc, you_function)`

Comment: Thanks for not only the functional assistance but also the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your desired result is, but is this close?

```
test <- data.frame(loc = c("(37.7862913318072, -122.401375181471)",
                           "(37.7646938184545, -122.449439257453)",
                           "(37.7860078381928, -122.430650176965)"))
test$loc <- gsub("[\\(\\)]", "", test$loc)
lonlat <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(test$loc,","))
lonlat <- matrix(as.numeric(lonlat), nrow(lonlat))
lonlat

#          [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 37.78629 -122.4014
# [2,] 37.76469 -122.4494
# [3,] 37.78601 -122.4307
```

Comment: You should probably add `as.numeric` in there somewhere, since you're hiding a "space" in the beginning of each `X2`. (And their `factor`s.)

Comment: Really clever solution. I was also looking for an explanation of the apply family so I had to give alex.h the answer but I'll definitely keep this trick mind.